# Get User Account Image

Tags: cocoa, macos

Simply: how do I get the user's account image?

I'm using Cocoa on Mac.

Comment: @Radek Pro-Grammer: "Cocoa" means he's using Objective-C.

Comment: @Dave DeLong: that is untrue for at least 100%. Ruby and Python bindings are available, and Assembly is also an option.

Comment: @Radek fair enough, though if he were using the Ruby or Python bridges he *probably* would've specified.  Regardless, you're correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The **Address Book** method **doesn't work if the user deletes the vcard**.

I use the **CBIdentity** method that never breaks, as Dave says:

```
+ (NSImage *)userImage
{
    CBIdentity *identity = [CBIdentity identityWithName:NSUserName() authority:[CBIdentityAuthority defaultIdentityAuthority]];
    return [identity image];
}
```

In order to use CBIdentity you need to add the **Collaboration Framework** to your targets and use the following include directive

```
#import <Collaboration/Collaboration.h>
```

Comment: when I use this, I get a nil for `[identity image]`, but my image is a cupcake in System Preferences :/

Comment: Is there a way to be notified if the image changes?

Comment: @LoyalTingley Did you find any solution to your problem? I think I'm hitting the same problem. For me, the image returned by that API for any admin users is nil.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want an image for the logged-in user, it's also possible to get it with a one-liner using AddressBook:

```
NSData *imgData = [[[ABAddressBook sharedAddressBook] me] imageData];
```

but I believe that this is not *guaranteed* to be the same as the log-in image.

Comment: Yea, I really do want the User account image (log-in image), not just the user's address book profile image, if possible. Thanks anyway

Comment: @magikseb Then I expect Dave's method is the way to go, which is why I voted it up! :)

Comment: +1 going through Address Book is a very interesting idea.  I don't know if it's what the OP wants, but it's a great place to look for info.

Comment: I think this will do for me. It didn't work at first because I didn't create a card for myself by pressing the button in System Preferences. This might be bad, but I put in the help to go to Sys Prefs => Accounts, click the button etc. for it to work fine.

Comment: @magikseb: I _think_ that when a user account is set up, an Address Book card is too, but I'm not positive. The user can change or delete the card, of course. I deleted mine.

Answer (score 3):

If you can get a handle to a `CSIdentityRef` or a `CBIdentity*` that represents the user in question, then you can invoke the `-[CBIdentity image]` method to retrieve their account image.

Edit:

Here's a previous answer of mine that shows how to query for all standard user accounts on a system and convert them into `CBIdentity` objects:  [Get all Users on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681895/get-all-users-on-os-x/3682039#3682039)

If you don't want to link against Collaboration.framework, then you can use something like [`CSIdentityImageGetData`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/IdentityServices_Ref/CSIdentity/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CSIdentityGetImageData) (or one of the similar variants) to get the image directly.  I personally find working with a native Cocoa object to be nicer, but in this case it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: I'm sorry, but having researched this a bit, I'm still not sure how to code this?

Comment: Is there any way to be notified if the image changed? The CSIdentity query callback doesn't seem to notice changes to the image