# How can I get the logged-in user's profile picture?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

macOS allows users to set a profile picture for their local accounts. This picture can be modified in the Accounts system preference pane and is notably displayed at login. Is there a way to access it using Cocoa or some other system framework?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get User Account Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423770/get-user-account-image)

Comment: @Willeke, macOS has the iCloud profile photo and the user account photo and they are separate. This gets you the iCloud profile photo. It’s not bad, I guess? I could arguably use either. One thing I don’t like about it is that there will be a consent prompt to access contacts on newer versions of macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is accessible from Open Directory, as is suggested by `dscl . -read /Users/my_user_name_here` having both a `JPEGPhoto` and a `Picture` attribute. The Open Directory framework is rather ancient: documentation is sparse and examples are almost inexistant, but while digging I found a [Python test](https://github.com/apple/ccs-pyosxframeworks/blob/master/osx/test/test_opendirectory.py) in an Apple repository that shows just enough how to use the API to get started. I finally came up with this:

```
NSData *getODImage(NSString *userName) {
    ODNode *local = [ODNode nodeWithSession:ODSession.defaultSession name:@"/Local/Default" error:nil];
    if (!local) {
        return nil;
    }
    ODRecord *record = [local recordWithRecordType:kODRecordTypeUsers name:userName attributes:nil error:nil];
    if (!record) {
        return nil;
    }
    NSArray *photoAttributes = @[kODAttributeTypePicture, kODAttributeTypeJPEGPhoto];
    NSDictionary *details = [record recordDetailsForAttributes:photoAttributes error:nil];
    if (!details) {
        return nil;
    }

    NSData *jpegData = [details[kODAttributeTypeJPEGPhoto] objectAtIndex:0];
    if (jpegData) {
        return jpegData;
    }

    for (NSString *picturePath in details[kODAttributeTypePicture]) {
        NSData *pictureContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:picturePath];
        if (pictureContents) {
            return pictureContents;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

where `userName` is the result of `NSUserName()`. This seems to execute fast locally, but I still have it run from a concurrent queue to avoid blocking the main thread.

The picture path returned through `kODAttributeTypePicture` is in the global `/Library` directory, which is accessible for reading from the default sandbox. This is the case for all default user pictures. It might not always be true, however, so prepare for not having a picture.

Correctness-speaking, YMMV when the user is a network user; I think that you'd have to change the node from /Local/Default to something else.