# Get list of users that can log in to a Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, user-accounts

How can I get list of users that can log in to OS X? That is, users that appear in the login window.

I know about [Get all Users on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681895/get-all-users-on-os-x)

This solution works for only 64 bit architecture. When I switch to 32 bit, it gives all users.

And I do not want to enumerate the Users directory, as a user's home directory can be moved to another location, and other directories can be created inside /Users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using provided [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681895/get-all-users-on-os-x) in question we can retrieve all users.

and the answer to question:

we get CBIdentity object, That object has isHidden flag this is true if user is visible on login window.

Ex:

```
bool isTrue = [identityObject isHidden];
if(isTrue)
{
    NSLog("User is login user");
}
```