# Objective C: How to programmatically check guest login permission preference in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, authorization

I am able to get a list of all users (*see: [Get all Users on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681895/get-all-users-on-os-x)*), but how can I identify that a guest user is allowed on Mac OS X.

We can toggle guest login permission in "Users and Groups" in "System Preferences". Can I check this setting programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

We can read GuestEnabled key from com.apple.loginwindow.plist file stored in library preferences.

```
 NSMutableDictionary *plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist"]];


BOOL isEnabled =  [[plistDict objectForKey:@"GuestEnabled"] boolValue];
```